# Clearing mocks after each test jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am learning Jest and I see this clearAllMocks function being used, I then check the docs and the description is simply this:

> Clears the mock.calls and mock.instances properties of all mocks.
> Equivalent to calling .mockClear() on every mocked function.
>
> Returns the jest object for chaining.

It basically says what you could already figure out by reading the function name. I still can't figure out when should I use this and why is this useful. Could you name an example when this would be good to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jest.clearAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) is often used during tests set up/tear down.

```
afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
});
```

Doing so ensures that information is not stored between tests which could lead to false assertions. Let's say that you have a mock function mockFn and you call the function, you can assert that it's been called 1 time. If in another test you call mockFn again but you have not cleared the mock, it would have been called two times now instead of one.

Answer (score 4):

This can be set in Jest config file which is equivalent to calling `jest.clearAllMocks()` before each test.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#clearmocks-boolean

```
// jest.config.js
{
  // ...rest
  "clearMocks": true
}
```