# Jest mock different return values for a function in each test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to have different values returned for the same mock in each Test.
I am using `mockReturnValueOnce` for returning different values in each call of a test.
But for further test when I use `mockImplementationOnce` it still returns `mockReturnValue`.

```
const mock = require('module-to-mock');

jest.mock('module-to-mock');

describe('tests', () => {

  it('test #1', async () => {
    mock.foo = jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce(1) // First call
      .mockReturnValueOnce(2) // Seconds call
      .mockReturnValue("default"); // Rest of the calls

    // execute test 
  });

  it('test #2', async () => {
    mock.foo.mockImplementationOnce(() => 3);
    // It is not working I am getting "default"
    
    // execute test 
  });

});
```

I did try resetting the mock using `mock.foo.mockReset()`, but it did not help. I did add it at the end of each test, once the test is executed. I also try by adding at the beginning of each test.

I have common mock implementation for all the functions in `module-to-mock` in a separate file.
I just want to remove/reset the mock done in the `test #1` and move to the original mock done in a separate file.

Comment: Where and how did you use `mockReset`? - Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/65819821/989920 help?

Comment: I did add it at the end of each test, once the test is executed. 
I also try it by adding at the beginning of each test.

Comment: The code you are showing works and returns `3` in the second test. Please try to create a minimal reproducible example